# Columns of a Linear Transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis, similar-matrices

Gilbert Strang, *Linear Algebra and it's applications* Pg 129

> Suppose the vectors $x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}$ are a basis for the space $\mathbf{V}$, and vectors $y_{1}, \ldots, y_{m}$ are a basis for $\mathbf{W}$. Each linear transformation $T$ from $\mathbf{V}$ to $\mathbf{W}$ is represented by a matrix $A$. The $j$ th column is found by applying $T$ to the $j$ th basis vector $x_{j}$, and writing $T\left(x_{j}\right)$ as a combination of the $y$ 's:
> Column $j$ of $A \quad T\left(x_{j}\right)=A x_{j}=a_{1 j} y_{1}+a_{2 j} y_{2}+\cdots+a_{m j} y_{m} .$

I can understand its proof if the basis of $\mathbf V$ are the standard unit vectors, but can't see how this can be proven for a general basis set.

Can anyone please show me how to derive it? Thank you

Comment: Instead of a representative matrix $\mathcal M_{\mathcal E}^{\mathcal E}(T)$, you'll have $\mathcal M_{\mathcal U}^{\mathcal V}(T)$, where $\mathcal E$ is the standard basis ($e_1,e_2,\dots e_n$) and $\mathcal U,\mathcal V$ are two generic bases.

Comment: If you want give me a linear function and I could show you an example

Answer (score 0):

Let $A: \bf V\rightarrow W$, $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ be a basis of $\bf V$, $(w_1,\ldots,w_m)$ -- a basis of $\bf W$. In its own basis $v_1=(1,0,\ldots,0)$, $v_2=(0,1,0,\ldots,0)$ and so on. Plugging it as input for the operator $A=(a_{ij})$ we have $Av_1 = (a_{11},\ldots,a_{m1})=a_{11}w_1+\ldots+a_{m1}w_m$. The same for all $v_i$.